# Summation of 2 floating point values gives incorrect result with higher precision

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, floating-point

The sum of 2 floating values in postgres gives the result with higher precision.
**Expected:**

```
669.05 + 1.64 = 670.69
```

**Actual:**

```
SELECT CAST(669.05 AS FLOAT) + CAST(1.64 AS FLOAT)
------------------
670.6899999999999
```

The result is having higher precision than expected.

The same operation with different set of inputs behaves differently.

```
SELECT CAST(669.05 AS FLOAT) + CAST(1.63 AS FLOAT)
------------------
670.68
```

Here I have reduced the problem statement by finding the 2 numbers for which the issue exists.
The actual problem is when I do this on a whole table the result would be very big with higher precisions (depending on the values, and I do not have an explanation for exactly what/kind of values the precision shoots up) and we had to handle the scale in the application level.
Example query

```
SELECT numeric_column_1/ CAST(numeric_column_2 AS FLOAT) FROM input_table;
```

Note: The behaviour is same for FLOAT(53) as well.

Comment: That is because decimal values (base 10) cannot be exactly represented in binary (base 2).  See documentation [Numeric Types: Floating-Point Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT).  Thus `float` data type are *always* approximations. Your best bet limit the precision to 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per postgresql documentation, float uses inexact precision. Better to use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`, which supports exact user specified precision.

```
SELECT CAST(669.05 AS numeric) + CAST(1.64 AS numeric)
```

[Floating-Point Types in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)

> The data types real and double precision are inexact,
> variable-precision numeric types. On all currently supported
> platforms, these types are implementations of IEEE Standard 754 for
> Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (single and double precision,
> respectively), to the extent that the underlying processor, operating
> system, and compiler support it.

### Numeric Types

| Name | Storage Size | Description | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smallint | 2 bytes | small-range integer | -32768 to +32767 |
| integer | 4 bytes | typical choice for integer | -2147483648 to +2147483647 |
| bigint | 8 bytes | large-range integer | -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807 |
| decimal | variable | user-specified precision, exact | up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point |
| numeric | variable | user-specified precision, exact | up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point |
| real | 4 bytes | variable-precision, inexact | 6 decimal digits precision |
| double precision | 8 bytes | variable-precision, inexact | 15 decimal digits precision |
| smallserial | 2 bytes | small autoincrementing integer | 1 to 32767 |
| serial | 4 bytes | autoincrementing integer | 1 to 2147483647 |
| bigserial | 8 bytes | large autoincrementing integer | 1 to 9223372036854775807 |

DB Fiddle: [Try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6b0a08486535ad02d81142a9b8048d72)